# Convert Swift Set to NSMutableSet

Tags: swift, type-conversion, set, nsset

I can convert from NSMutableSet to Set no problem, but I'm running into problems when doing the reverse.

E.g. this works:

```
let nsSet = NSMutableSet(array: ["a", "b"])
let swiftSet = nsSet as! Set<String>
```

But when I try:

```
let nsSet2 = swiftSet as? NSMutableSet
```

`nsSet2` ends up being `nil`.

Comment: Don't do that. Don't use `NSMutable...` collection types in Swift at all. `Set` with `var` is mutable for free (and type safe).

Comment: @vadian needed to store in NSUserDefaults, for example

Comment: I doubt that. `NS(Mutable)Set` is not a property list compliant type

Comment: @vadian: yup, you're right. Turns out I was [looking at NSKeyValueCoding methods instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49018417/35690).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like swift Sets need to be converted to NSSet first:

```
let nsSet2 = NSMutableSet(set: set as NSSet)
```

Or shorthand:

```
let nsSet2 = NSMutableSet(set: set)
```

Or to go from NSSet to Swift Set and back to NSSet:

```
let nsSet = NSMutableSet(array: ["a", "b"])
let set = nsSet as! Set<String>
let nsSet2 = set as NSSet
let nsSet3 = NSMutableSet(set: nsSet2)
```