# Store NSMutableSet to NSUserDefaults

Tags: swift, set, nsuserdefaults, nsmutableset

I want to store a Swift Set in NSUserDefaults.

Given that I can read a NSMutableSet value from UserDefaults using:

```
UserDefaults.standard.mutableSetValue(forKey:)
```

... it seems like I should be able to write a NSMutableSet too.

I tried [converting my Set to NSMutableSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49017356/convert-swift-set-to-nsmutableset), but when I try to save it in UserDefaults it says:

> [User Defaults] Attempt to set a non-property-list object {(
>       foo
>   )} as an NSUserDefaults/CFPreferences value for key KEYNAME

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`mutableSetValue(forKey:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1415105-mutablesetvalue) has an unfortunate name.

Most of the [UserDefaults methods](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults) look *very* similar:

- [`array(forKey:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1414792-array)
- [`bool(forKey:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1416388-bool)
- [`dictionary(forKey:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1408563-dictionary)
- [`object(forKey:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1410095-object)
- [`set(_:forKey:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1414067-set)

However, [`mutableArrayValue(forKey:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1416339-mutablearrayvalue) is actually coming from the [NSKeyValueCoding](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/object_runtime/nskeyvaluecoding) protocol!

This protocol has methods such as:

- [`mutableArrayValue(forKey:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1416339-mutablearrayvalue)
- [`mutableSetValue(forKey:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1415105-mutablesetvalue)
- [`value(forKey:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1412591-value)
- [`setValue(_:forKey:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1415969-setvalue)

When dealing with UserDefaults, you likely want to only use the methods from the [UserDefaults list](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults) instead of the [NSKeyValueCoding](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/object_runtime/nskeyvaluecoding) list.

In short, you'll want to make sure you're not looking at the NSKeyValueCoding methods, avoid trying to read/write a Set, and write a [property-list object](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/PropertyList.html) instead:

> Property lists consist only of certain types of data: dictionaries, arrays, strings, numbers (integer and float), dates, binary data, and Boolean values.